# Questino about integration of differential forms

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Here is the theorem about the integration of two-forms in Edwards' "Advanced Calculus"

[image]

The definitions of "charts" in this theorem are given here.
[image]

What I do not understand about the Theorem is the orientation of the domain of integration by *dudv*.

Why do we oriented the domain in this way? Could I orient the domain instead by *dvdu*?

The "charts" as in the Theorem are not oriented in any particular way; it could be oriented by *dudv* or *dvdu*, as long as the orientation of the charts is consisitent.

Comment: You didn't include this in the portion you copied, but the charts have to map the $uv$-region, oriented by $du\,dv$, compatibly to the oriented surface. The notion of an oriented surface includes the ability to cover the surface by such compatibly oriented charts.

Comment: @TedShifrin Where does it say in the book that the the uv-region is oriented by *dudv*? I have the hardcopy of the book, but I do not see what you said I did not include

Comment: I don't have the complete text ... But note that the text above specifies in the statement of the theorem that "the domain of integration is oriented by $du\,dv$."

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the orientation (duddv=-dvdu) merely reverses the sign of all integrals. Nobody said you couldn't do it!